# How do I set READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION

Tags: java, sql-server

I would like to enable those parameter but I don't have enought rights to modify the data base code (because of my company). So, I was wondering if I can modify them while I'm creating the conecction with the data base or accessing to a store procedure by means of a Java application.

Comment: @Tichodroma: those are properties of SQL Server

Comment: Yeah sql, sorry I have forgotten to write it :O

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for modifying these properties programmatically, then there too you will face the issue of **enough rights** which are already mentioned. This is irrespective of any programming language.

To answer your question: 
*I was wondering if I can modify them while I'm creating the connection*

A DB connection is always **associated with a user-name and password** or an account on the DB server. If the DBA has not **granted the rights** to change the DB properties, there is nothing you can do.

Not sure if you are confused these properties (READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT and ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION) with the [Isolation Levels](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/ebeans/ch08_03.htm) (which you can set on the connection object). These are different things. The former is very specific to MSSQL server which can be set by a DBA by [executing a query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Those are properties of the database, and if you don't have the rights to change them, then you don't have the rights. You require `ALTER` permission on the database itself.